# Display special character properly

Tags: swift, uilabel

When I read data from restful api, I have seen the following characters. I wonder how to handle this type of string to display properly.

```
"productName": "VIZIO��60\"��Class 4k Ultra HD LED Smart TV -��P602UI-B3",
```

Actual name is supposed to be as follows:

```
VIZIO  60\"  Class 4k Ultra HD LED Smart TV -  P602UI-B3
```

current implementation

```
cell.productNameLbl.text = product[indexPath.row].productName
```

Comment: It's up to the text encoder/decoder.

Comment: El Tomato is correct: it's an encoding issue.  You'll want to check that everything is consistent.  For example, here's an explanation as to how to set the character encoding on a webpage, you'll notice they're setting it it to UTF-8: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations